# Locust is gave me error when trying to running on my machine mac m1

Tags: python, performance-testing, load-testing, locust

**I have error when trying to run locust load test on my machine mac m1 it gaves me**

```
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/geventhttpclient/_parser.cpython-310-darwin.so, 0x0002):
tried: '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/geventhttpclient/_parser.cpython-310-darwin.so'
(mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64'))
```

i installed latest version of python : 3.10

i get that error when tryinfg to run :

```
locust -f file.py --csv=test --headless -r 5 -u 1 -t 60s
```

Comment: Check from `Activity Monitor`, the `Kind` of  your `python` process is `Intel` or `Apple`? If it is `Intel`, maybe you can try install the native version of python

Answer (score -1):

run VS code without checked *Open using Rosetta* helps me.